# How to remove No SIM found notification (Android 7.1.1 Nougat)

Tags: notifications, sim-card, sim-unlocking, notification-icons

I bought a new phone with ***Android 7.1.1 Nougat*** unlocked from Verizon. Since I bought it unlocked, I get a notification that says

> No SIM found, Tap for more information.

It really irritates me because it takes up screen real-estate and I sometimes tap on it by accident. Is there any way to get rid of this notification? (Also the icon on the left side with a SIM card with a strike through it.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you put the phone into Airplane Mode, it'll stop looking for a SIM card and the notification should go away. Of course this also disables Wifi put you can enable Wifi while it is still in Airplane Mode.

Comment: Footnote: you might be able to turn off the Mobile Data from the Settings but I can't confirm this until I am at home and have access to an Android phone without a SIM card.